# Conditional casting of column datatype

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, casting

i have subquery, that returns me varchar column, in some cases this column contains only numeric values and in this cases i need to cast this column to bigint, i`ve trying to use CAST(case...) construction, but CASE is an expression that returns a single result and regardless of the path it always needs to result in the same data type (or implicitly convertible to the same data type). Is there any tricky way to change column datatype depending on condition in PostgreSQL or not? google cant help me((

```
SELECT 
        prefix, 
        module, 
        postfix,
        id,
        created_date
        FROM 
           (SELECT 
           s."prefix", 
           coalesce(m."replica", to_char(CAST((m."id_type" * 10 ^ 12) AS bigint) + m."id", 'FM0000000000000000')) "module", 
           s."postfix", 
           s."id",  
           s."created_date" 
           FROM some_subquery
```

Comment: Very difficult to understand you without a simple exaple. Can you add a simple query to demonstrate your case?

Comment: A single column can only have a single data type. You can't have different types in different rows for the same column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Couldn't (theoretically) all values be, let's say, either varchar or integer so the resulting query column type could change at runtime?

Comment: @Impaler depends on database column module can contain only numeric value or only non-numeric values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really no way to do what you want.

A SQL query returns a fixed set of columns, with the names and types being fixed.  So, *a priori* what you want to do does not fit well within SQL.

You could work around this, by inventing your own type, that is either a big integer or a string.  You could store the value as JSON.  But those are work-arounds.  The SQL query itself is really returning one "type" for each column; that is how SQL works.